Command to retrieve send/receive internet traffiic, (in bytes), per process
I want to create a batch file to terminate processes which exceed 'a certain amount of internet'.
I just want a command to show the internet usage, send/receive (bytes), of each application/process.
Actually, netstat seems to work for me? but idk how to use it.

Open a command prompt window, run netstat /? and read the output usage help. Microsoft documented this Windows command also on page about netstat. There is also the SS64 documentation for NETSTAT.exe with %SystemRoot%\System32\netstat.exe as fully qualified file name to use in a batch file.

Run for /? in the command prompt and read all output help pages carefully. for /F is usually used in a batch file for processing the output of an executable. The Stack Overflow search [[batch-file] or cmd] netstat lists lots of questions and answers with netstat usage as well as the Super User search [[batch-file] or cmd.exe] netstat.

Windows CMD itself does not provide a built-in way to measure internet usage per process directly.
But there is a Github project, nethogs, which may be useful to you.
